# XQuery: file:is-file() returns false

Tags: xquery, basex

I am executing the following XQuery code on BaseX 7.9 and the result is *false* even when I know it is a file (the dots are an abbreviation).

```
file:is-file("C:\Users\...\books2.xml")
```

According to http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:is-file I should be receiving *true*.

Comment: Is this the full path you're testing with, or did you abbreviate/anonymize it (which I'm pretty sure of). Please _always_ post code that produces the failure, read [ask] and [how to post an SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Did you also check that BaseX has read permissions on the file, what happens if you use `doc(...)` with the path you're using?

Comment: It is an abbreviation to anonymize it, indeed.

Comment: Does it work with other files? What do these functions return for this file: file:exists, file:is-dir?